# Group Policy for Blocking Windows 11 Upgrade Prompts

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

So now that Microsoft has rolled out their Windows 11 push, our company's endusers are getting the prompts. Going into Group Policy I made an change described here and other sources --> https://www.pdq.com/blog/how-to-block-the-windows-11-upgrade/. Here is the entry I made.

[image: GP Change]

After the change and a few reboots and issuing the ***gpupdate /force*** command on a test Windows 10 PC, the PC is still receiving the Windows 11 upgrade prompt. Looking in that PC's registry I do see the new keys/values added as expected. Any suggestions how to finally put this thing to bed? I don't have WSUS, and typically Group Policy is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our environment has a mix of Windows 10 21H1 and 21H2 PC's. The PC's on 21H1 still would see the Windows 11 upgrade prompt regardless of the Group Policy. The PC's on 21H2 would have the Windows 11 upgrade prompt removed. So apparently the only way this Group Policy will work as expected is if all clients are on that specific Windows 10 feature release that's specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Target Version to 21H1 instead.  The Windows 11 Feature Update is also considered 21H2 so that's why it is still being offered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The Windows 10 November 2021 ADMX files have two fields for specifying the target platform. So you are able to define both the product version (Windows 10) and the target version (21H2). So this isn't applicable, as shown in my screen shot above.