# Block Windows 11 via GPO without specifying sub-version

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

as shown in here

[Group Policy for Blocking Windows 11 Upgrade Prompts](https://serverfault.com/questions/1091251/group-policy-for-blocking-windows-11-upgrade-prompts)

Microsoft allows blocking the Windows 11 Update via a GPO, howver as far as it seems you have to specify both the main (e.g. `Windows 10`) and sub-version (e.g. `21H2`) of windows, can the field for the subversion be left empty or anything else be done so it properly keeps updating the sub version but stays on Windows 10.

After all you kinda have to have this policy as microsoft thought it's a great idea that non-Admins can be allowed running a Windows Upgrade to a whole new OS (which it isn't), so you have to have that setting in order to prevent users from just accidentially installing windows 11.

Comment: You could not deploy Windows 11.

Comment: @GregAskew We dont actively deploy Windows 11 in the first place, but Windows Update just says it's available and lets users install it without needing admin rights

Comment: I know you don't. But if you did control what is deployed to your endpoints, you could prevent it, instead of hoping for a setting that does not exist.

Comment: isnt that the point of the policy to control what the windows is getting? or what do you mean control what I deploy as MS is clearly taking the control away considering we have deployed windows 10 and the users can just go to win11 without permission